# Header image placement on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, image, header

My header image on my website (dorinart.com) is perfectly positioned in all browsers including android mobile browsers but when I open it on IOS (iphone, ipad) it only shows the top right corner of the image (you can check if you open dorinart.com). How could I resolve this issue?

my css looks like this:

```
.header{
    background: url('../img/banner5.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 730px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: can you share screenshot of the same here?

Comment: I guess CSS position: fixed; won't work in iOS Safari.

Comment: @ArpitLokwani what can I use instead?

Comment: .header{
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    @media (max-width: @iphone-screen) {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}             // use media query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this CSS? I think you want to center the image in the space available right? Please let me know if this works:

```
.header{
   background-image: url('../img/banner5.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position-x: center;
   min-height: 760px;
   position: relative;
}
```

If you don't want it centered, then just remove the `background-position-x` property.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Update: Attached screenshot from simulator:

[image]

Comment: Tried it but it still looks the same.

Comment: @Dorina Works for me on the Simulator. I have attached a screenshot. Please have a look.

Comment: yes I tried it in simulators before and everything worked fine but on the real device it's not okay

Comment: @Dorina Just tried these changes via a web-inspector (on my macbook safari) while opening the site on an iPhone 7 and it seems to work. Are you sure you have these changes deployed? because I cannot see them updated on the site. Can you please do that?

Comment: It works now!! Thank you soo much seriously!! Do you happen to know a solution to make the effects on my portfolio items work as well?

Comment: @Dorina Glad to have helped! Please do upvote and accept the answer (tick mark below the down/up buttons). What are the problems you are facing on the portfolio items?

Comment: when you view them in the browser you can see they turn and you can read a little summary of them but this function doesn't work on ios (it works on android)

Comment: Sure! I'll have a look. By the way, the flipping problem is also reproducible on safari on the desktop. Seems like the rotateY property is not working. I'll have a look, please do lend me some time. Thanks for accepting the answer!

Comment: @Dorian For the flipping issue on mobile safari, can you try the following: Add the following property to the following selector `.portfolio-item figure img` : `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and also add the same property to the following selector: `.portfolio-item figure figcaption` : `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`. Seems to be working on my simulator after I added these two classes. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: It's working now!! thank you so much for your help I appreciate it a lot!!

Comment: @Dorina Glad to be of help :) Cheers and by the way, you got a nice site coming up there (I am assuming it's yours) :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue recently and realised that it's due to `background-size:cover` with `background-attachment:fixed`.

In your website its like this:

```
background: url('../img/banner5.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 760px;
position: relative;
```

Here the `background-attachment:fixed` is the problem.

I solved the issue by using a media query for iPhone and setting background-attachment property to scroll.

So what you can do is use this:

```
.header{
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    @media (max-width: @iphone-screen) {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this as well, doesn't change anything on iphone but makes the rest of the website messed up on ipad